# Null object in promise Angular2

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ionic2

i'm developing an Ionic2 app and I'm using promises. In a Typescript class I have created this method

```
tapOnRegistrati() {
this.authService.userRegistration(this.email,this.password).then(function(user){

  this.user = this.af.database.object('/users/' + user.uid);
  this.user.set({ name: this.name, lastname: this.lastname});


}).catch(function(error: any) {

});

}
```

but when the `then` block is executed `this`'s reference is `null`, so I can't use any object/attribute of my typescript class. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because if you use your callback function like

```
.then(function(user){
  this.user = this.af.database.object('/users/' + user.uid);
  this.user.set({ name: this.name, lastname: this.lastname});    
})
```

`this` will refer to the function object inside the callback. If you want to refer to the page, use:

```
then((user)=>{
  this.user = this.af.database.object('/users/' + user.uid);
  this.user.set({ name: this.name, lastname: this.lastname});

})
```